# Entanglement and Special Relativity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, quantum-entanglement, causality, locality

There are 2 particles entangled and move far apart to 2 measuring devices . The first measurement of either particle will collapse the wave function and set spin up and spin down on the particles. 2 observers are watching from far away in different frames of reference. Observer #1 sees particle A get measured first and Observer #2 sees particle B get measured first. Which measurement collapses the wave function and how can either particle affect the other when you can't tell which measurement occurred first.

My problem is saying something happens instantly when the wave function collapses seems to require Newtonian absolute time, special relativity allows the timing Events to be up to the observer. Does this bother anyone else?

Comment: This question ("Does this bother you?") is one of the types of questions we [strive to avoid here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) because it is entirely subjective.

Comment: The correlation in an EPR type experiment doesn't happen instantly. It happens while your computer is calculating the correlation function, i.e. way after there was not even a collapse of the wave function (that's just a fancy term for Born's rule). You need to hone your intuition about what is really happening vs. what naive folks assume is happening.

Comment: You're definitely thinking about important issues here, but unfortunately, as worded, this question is not appropriate for this site. Can you ask a more objective question? By the way, this quesiton will probably get closed due to being subjective. Don't worry! Just fix it up and then submit it for re-opening :)

Answer (score 1):

In the entangled system we do not have two separate particles. Instead we have a single wavefunction describing a single system. When you interact with the wavefunction you are not interacting with particle $A$ or with particle $B$, you are interacting with a single wavefunction and causing it to change as a result.

So the statement *measuring $A$ affects $B$* (or vice versa) is simply not true. Interacting with the wavefunction causes the whole wavefunction to change. The final states of $A$ and $B$ are correlated, but one doesn't cause the other.

And this removes the confusion of how one observer can see $A$ apparently causing $B$ while a different observer sees $B$ apparently causing $A$, because is no cause and effect to be seen.